# How to create three step nesting using Hugo?

Tags: hugo

I need to create three-step nested  Country -> region -> City.
Using static site generator Hugo I know how to create only two-step nested because Hugo have default names for templates (list and single )

[see](https://prnt.sc/nqv0by) at the folder posts

But I don't know how to create three-step nested.

Thanks, everyone for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to accomplish this: For every page under the nested section `content/country/region/city`, add the front matter param `type: nested`.

Then create file `layouts/nested/single.html` with your single template.